# Strip A specific part from a url string in python

Tags: python, strip

Im passing through some urls and I'd like to strip a part of it which dynamically changes so I don't know it firsthand.
An example `url` is:

```
https://...?pid=2&gid=lostchapter&lang=en_GB&practice=1&channel=desktop&demo=2
```

And I'd like to strip the `gid=lostchapter` part without any of the rest.

How do I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "strip", exactly? Remove it from the URL? Extract it? Do you want to reconstruct the URL without it present?

Comment: I want to extract it  as a stand-alone string and use it elsewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `urllib` to convert the query string into a Python `dict` and access the desired item:

```py
In [1]: from urllib import parse

In [2]: s = "https://...?pid=2&gid=lostchapter&lang=en_GB&practice=1&channel=desktop&demo=2"

In [3]: q = parse.parse_qs(parse.urlsplit(s).query)

In [4]: q
Out[4]:
{'pid': ['2'],
 'gid': ['lostchapter'],
 'lang': ['en_GB'],
 'practice': ['1'],
 'channel': ['desktop'],
 'demo': ['2']}

In [5]: q["gid"]
Out[5]: ['lostchapter']
```

Comment: How can I get it as a simple string? I mean like  `lostchapter`

Comment: `q["gid"][0]` will pull the value out of the list. The reason `parse_qs` function always turns query strings into `Dict[str, List[str]]` is because of how query strings can be formed (i.e., query string parameters can be used more than once).

Answer (score 1):

We can try doing a regex replacement:

```py
url = "https://...?pid=2&gid=lostchapter&lang=en_GB&practice=1&channel=desktop&demo=2"
output = re.sub(r'(?<=[?&])gid=lostchapter&?', '', url)
print(output)  # https://...?pid=2&lang=en_GB&practice=1&channel=desktop&demo=2
```

For a more generic replacement, match on the following regex pattern:

```
(?<=[?&])gid=\w+&?
```

Comment: And how do I obtain the `gid=lostchapter` ? I want to strip it and make it a stand-alone string

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple way to strip them

```
urls = "https://...?pid=2&gid=lostchapter&lang=en_GB&practice=1&channel=desktop&demo=2"

# Import the `urlparse` and `urlunparse` methods
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlunparse

# Parse the URL
url = urlparse(urls)

# Convert the `urlparse` object back into a URL string
url = urlunparse(url)

# Strip the string
url = url.split("?")[1]
url = url.split("&")[1]
# Print the new URL
print(url) # Prints "gid=lostchapter"
```

Comment: This is a brittle solution. What if the desired query parameter is not first in the query string?

Answer (score 1):

Using string slicing (I'm assuming there will be an '&' after `gid=lostchapter`)

```
url = r'https://...?pid=2&gid=lostchapter&lang=en_GB&practice=1&channel=desktop&demo=2'
start = url.find('gid')
end = start + url[url.find('gid'):].find('&')
url = url[start:] + url[:end-1]
print(url)
```

output

```
gid=lostchapter
```

What I'm trying to do here is:

- find index of occurrence of "gid"
- find the first "&" after "gid" is found
- concatenate the parts of the url after"gid" and before "&"

Answer (score 1):

## Method 1: Using UrlParsers

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse
p = urlparse('https://.../?pid=2&gid=lostchapter&lang=en_GB&practice=1&channel=desktop&demo=2')
param: list[str] = [i for i in p.query.split('&') if i.startswith('gid=')]
```

Output: `gid=lostchapter`

## Method 2: Using Regex

```py
param: str = re.search(r'gid=.*&', 'https://.../?pid=2&gid=lostchapter&lang=en_GB&practice=1&channel=desktop&demo=2').group()[:-1]
```

you can change the regex pattern to appropriate pattern to match the expected outputs. currently it will extract any value.